# Remove Text from Element Without Removing Reference

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace all the text in some element (including text in children) with some other text. For example, the html

```
<div id="myText">
    This is some text.
    This is some other text.
    <p id="toHide">
        This is even more text.
        Click this text to hide it.
    </p>
</div>
```

should become

```
<div id="myText">
    That is some text.
    That is some other text.
    <p id="toHide">
        That is even more text.
        Click That text to hide it.
    </p>
</div>
```

Essentially, I've replaced all of `/this/gi` with `"That"`. However, I **cannot** use the following:

```
$("#myText").innerHTML = $("#myText").innerHTML.replace(/this/gi, "");
```

This is because I keep a lot of references to the children of `myText`. This references will be erased. I realize that in simple cases, I can just update these references, but I have a fairly large file, and many references (and it would be troublesome and error prone to have to update **every** reference every time this function is called).

I also store some data not visible to `innerHTML`. For example, I use

```
$("#toHide").test = "test";
```

This is lost when writing to `innerHTML`.

How can I replace text in a div without `innerHTML` (preferably without jquery)?

**Jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/ZEfM7/

Comment: @Oriol I use `$` as a shortcut to `document.querySelector` (see jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOM` methods (a.k.a. the old and safe way)

```
function replaceText(el, pattern, txt) {
    for(var i=0; i<el.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        switch(node.nodeType){
            case 1: // Element
                replaceText(node, pattern, txt); continue;
            case 3: // Text node
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/this/gi, "that"); continue;
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEfM7/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
var n, walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.getElementById("myText"), NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while (n = walker.nextNode()) {
    n.nodeValue = n.nodeValue.replace(/this/ig, "that");
}
```

Basically, walk all the text nodes, and substitute their values.

---

For better compatibility, here's some reusable code:

```
function visitTextNodes(el, callback) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        callback(el);
    }

    for (var i=0; i < el.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        visitTextNodes(el.childNodes[i], callback);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
visitTextNodes(document.getElementById("myText"), function(el) {
    el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace(/this/ig, "that");
});
```

Comment: Documentation for `createTreeWalker` seems sparse. Could you explain what it does? (I'm guessing it's some sort of filtering/iterating mechanism). What is its browser support?

Comment: @soktinpk See [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker), which has a [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker#Browser_compatibility) section.

Comment: Think of it as an iterator over a set of filtered nodes. You'll find browser compatibility at the botton of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker). And here are the [TreeWalker object docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)

Comment: @Lucas It seems that Internet Explorer (even 10 and 11) doesn't support the second argument, which you use for filtering, so I don't think I can use this solution.

Comment: Oops. Ok, then I guess the only thing left you've got is to iterate the oldschool way.

Comment: Just added the "oldschool" way, just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Here my version of `replaceText`:

```
function replaceText(elem) {
    if(elem.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        elem.nodeValue = elem.nodeValue.replace(/this/gi, 'that')
        return
    }
    var children = elem.childNodes
    for(var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i)
        replaceText(children[i]);
}
```

**NB** this take an element as the first parameter and traverse all children, hence it works even with complex elements.

Here the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEfM7/6/

Comment: I'm fairly confident that my elements will only be one level deep, but this is a good solution for anyone with a more complex element. So +1 anyway